# UITableView not filling entire height of iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Using Xcode 7.2, Autolayout, I have a UITableViewController embedded in a Container View.

The Container View was added view the Story Board and dragged to the edges of its super view. The UITableViewController was added to the Story Board from the Object Library. I am not using any Constraints to "lock" the width and height to the Container View's Super View but I don't think I should have to.

I am not using any constraints at all, in fact, I have just dragged the 4 edges of the Container View to the Super View 4 edges and the UITableViewController was dragged into the Story Board from the object library and embedded in the Container View.

The Super View of the Container View Autolayout is `Any Any` and the UITableViewController Autolayout is `Any Any`.

I have no issues with iPhone 5 but iPhone6 plus you can see in the screenshot of the iPhone simulator below.

This is not an issue of not having enough rows, there are more rows in the UITableViewController if you scroll in the iPhone simulator.

My Container View is dragged to the 4 edges of the Super View and says the following if I even wanted to add constraints:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I am not using many Constraints to "lock" the width and height to the Container View's Super View but I don't think I should have to." Would you be able to add what constraints you *are* using? If you have leading/trailing/top/bottom and this problem still occurs then it's a very interesting one.

Comment: Hi @TwoStraws So for the Container view, I have dragged the edges to the Super View so I do not I think I can really add constraints to the Container view, check out the screen shot I added to my question, this is with the Container View selected in the Storyboard, I can't add constraints to the Container View, and the UITableViewController should be full width and height, it is embedded in the Container View

Comment: Wait… is it a UITableView or a UITableViewController? (It's late here; my eyes are getting tired!)

Comment: Its a UITableViewController embedded in a Container View

Comment: Would you be so kind as to try adding the leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints for your container view? Pin it to the edges of the view it's inside. I believe this will solve your problem.

Comment: NB: Your comment "says the following if I even wanted to add constraints" suggests you think it's not possible to add constraints for the container view. That message isn't stopping you, it's just saying that in lieu of user constraints some system-generated constraints will be used. Ctrl-drag to add constraints as necessary.

Comment: I haven't heard back from you, but I feel confident this is the solution to your problem so I posted it as a formal answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Interface Builder does when you use a container view is place a `UIView` into your storyboard, then add some connection options that aren't usually there. As a result, the usual Auto Layout rules still apply: your container view was not resizing, so its child `UITableViewController` was also not resizing.

Anyone else who encounters this problem can resolve it just by adding constraints for the leading, trailing, top and bottom edges of their container view.

Answer (score 3):

**The answer is in the question:**

> I am not using any constraints at all

**Use constraints.**

Add 4 `Autoloayout` constraints, edge to edge, vertically & horizontally:

1. top to bottom of top layout guide
2. leading to container leading
3. trailing to contrainer trailing
4. bottom to top of bottom layout guide

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SwiftArchitect, although you answer achieves better detail TwoStraws is correct as well and he was working with me on this problem longer so I marked his answer correct.